# error 503 in iis 7 suddenly happens every few minutes

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, iis

I have asp.net application runs on iis 7. Until today everything works fine (for a few months).
Today I got a strange problem. Every couple of minutes the site crashes and I get "error 503 service unavailable". When making IISRESET the problem solved until the next crush. When opening the event viewer on the server, I found that there is an error every few minutes that related to the w3wp proccess. I believe that this is makes the error 503 I get but I don't know why it happens and how can I solve this.

Here is the error in the event viewer:
[image]

Here is the problem itself:
[image]

I really appriciate any assistance.

***UPDATE:***
After looking in the exent viewer I saw there is stack overflow somewhere in my application - but I don't know how I get the full exception in order to find where it accurs. Any ideas?
I found this somewhere: [this](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1170/log-application-error-details-in-windows-event-viewer/). Does this will help me to find out?

***UPDATE2:***
The problem is one of my webservices makes stackoverflow exception. I don;t know which one. How can I get the exception and the stack trace? How can I trace my webservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [503 error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html) means your server is temporarly unavailable due to overload. This probably means you are suddenly getting a lot of users, while the [hosted websites are not well-optimized](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) (e.g. too many HTTP requests per page).

**EDIT**: Try enabling debugging mode in IIS, with the **Log Errors to NT Log** option.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731782.aspx

Comment: As clarification, 503 does not mean overload. It means the server is unavailable to serve a request. That could be overload, temp restart, or anything else that caused the server to be offline.

Comment: **The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).** As Naor didn't change anything, he most certainly is facing a server overload. Plus, it isn't about a restart, as (not) specified in the log.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong in this situation, I'm saying that a 503 error can be more general than just "overloaded".

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding.